# Use post metadata or taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to build a wordpress based website where the major type of the post is movie like, for example, for a new article(movie), Apart from the general fields like `title` `name`, some extra fields like `director` `publish-time` `thumb` are also required.

After read the guide in wordpress.org, it seems that the post metadata can be used, however I also need some fields can be query-able, for example, one can search movies published in a certain year or by the same director. Also I found the `Term` and `Taxonomy`, though I am not very clearly know about the two concepts, but seems like they are some kinds of things like category and tag.

Which is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

You should use both meta data and taxonomy.

For fields like published time, director, thumb you should use post meta since they will be different for every movie.

But genre, language, rating can be classified so you should use custom taxonomies like categories and tags.

Regarding querying both taxonomy and meta data can be used.

write custom WP_Query() arguments with meta_query and tax_query to filter results.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want custom fields? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
Querying for the field will be as simple as get_field('field_name').

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom **taxonomy** using custom **WP_Query()** arguments with **meta_query** and **tax_query** to filter results That allready described by @lax mariappan. For more information check wordpress documentation.